# Evaluating nascent delta function limit with principal value

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, dirac-delta, cauchy-principal-value

I strongly suspect, but am unable to prove, that the following limit holds (in the sense of distributions):

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\exp(i \omega t) -1}{i\omega} = \pi \delta(\omega)+i\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{\omega}\tag{1}\label{eq}$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ is a Cauchy principal value operator. The first term is easy to see, since the real part $\sin(\omega t)/\omega$ is a nascent delta function. Note that this expression is very similar to the Sokhotski-Plemelj formula

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\omega\pm i \epsilon}=\mp i\pi \delta(\omega)+\mathcal{P}\frac1\omega, $$
but this latter limit is easier to show.

*How does one prove Eq. \ref{eq}, in particular the principal value term?* The real reason I'm wondering is that I need to evaluate some more complicated limits, including

$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\left(\exp(i \omega_1 t) -1\right)\left(\exp(-i\omega_2 t)-1\right)}{\omega_1 \omega_2}. $$

Here, the interesting case is $\omega_1=\pm \omega_2$. I originally believed

$$ \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\left(\exp(i \omega_1 t) -1\right)\left(\exp(-i\omega_2 t)-1\right)}{\omega_1 \omega_2} =\begin{cases}
\pi^2 \delta(\omega_1) \delta(\omega_2), \, \omega_1 \ne \omega_2 \\
2 \pi t  \delta(\omega_1), \,  \omega_1 = \omega_2.
\end{cases}, $$
but now I am convinced I am missing some principal value terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a distribution, $\cos\omega t \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$ so
$$
\omega \frac{\cos\omega t - 1}{\omega}
= \cos\omega t - 1
\to 0 - 1 = -1
.
$$

From this we can conclude that
$$
\frac{\cos\omega t - 1}{\omega} 
\to -\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{\omega} + C \, \delta(\omega)
$$
for some constant $C.$

But the left hand side is odd, so the right hand side must also be odd, which requires $C=0.$

Thus,
$$
\frac{\cos\omega t - 1}{\omega} 
\to -\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{\omega}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\exp(i\omega t)-1}{i\omega}
= -i\frac{\cos\omega t - 1}{\omega} + \frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}
\to i \, \mathcal{P}\frac{1}{\omega} + \pi\,\delta(\omega)
.
$$

Comment: I realized that it practically boils down to
$$
\frac{\cos\omega t - 1}{\omega} = \cos\omega t \frac{1}{\omega} - \frac{1}{\omega}
\to 0 \cdot \frac{1}{\omega} - \frac{1}{\omega} = - \frac{1}{\omega}.
$$

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail/rigor where the principal value comes from? Would it be true that, say, $\frac{\cos^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2} = \frac{1+\cos(2\omega t))}{2\omega^2} \to {\cal P}\frac{1}{2\omega^2}$?

Comment: @mikefallopian. The principal value distribution $\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{\omega}$ is the almost unique distribution satisfying $\omega \, u(\omega) = 1.$ With "almost unique" I refer to that one can add multiples of $\delta(\omega).$

Comment: Up to scalar multiples, it _is_ the unique _odd_ distribution satisfying $\omega\cdot u=1$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @paulgarrett. "Up to scalar multiples"?

Comment: @md2perpe Ha! Thanks, I'll replace that comment with a better one. :)

Comment: The principal-value integral against $1/x$ is the unique _odd_ distribution $\omega$ satisfying $x\cdot \omega=1$.